# Google Sheets onEdit function not being called

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using check boxes to indicate that actions have been taken by a script, so I don't want the user to change the values in the check boxes. For a start, I thought I'd just pop up a warning telling them to change it back again.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const r = e.Range;
  Logger.log(r.getName);
  if (r.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Rules") {
    if (r.Column == 3) {
      Browser.msgBox("Do not alter the check boxes manually, click the icon in the Implement column");
    }
  }
}
```

I then created a trigger, so that the "On Edit" event calls the "OnEdit" function.

However, nothing is happening. What might I be doing wrong? The other functions are all still working.

The "Last Run" is being updated on the trigger screen, though. So I think it is running, but not doing what I want. The check boxes are all in Column C of the Rules tab.

*Update*

Ok thanks for all the pointers on the silly mistakes I made. This is now working:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const r = e.range;
  if (r.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Rules") {
    if (r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getRow() > 1) {
      r.setValue(!r.getValue());
      Browser.msgBox("Do not alter the check boxes manually, click the triangle in the Implement column");
    }
  }
}
```

Also I can't see any way to disable the email alerts. All the searches lead to instructions that do not work. If I share this with other people, and they save their own copies in their Google Drive, will they get the emails or will I?

Comment: `````e.range`````

Comment: As well as `r.Column` should be `r.getColumn()` and `r.getName` should be `r.getSheet().getName()`

Comment: The problem with your existing code is just actually syntax issue and the proper calling of methods in range class. Your issue is actually solved by `TheMaster` and `TheWizEd` comments.

Comment: Thanks all for pointing out my silly mistakes, I haven't touched AppScript for a while.